# D3.queue -- understanding program flow

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying really understand the program flow for d3.queue.

I have cooked up the following example.

Perhaps this example and the answer might help others understand this tricky pattern.

At the moment, I have the following:

```
var finished = function(error, results) {
 console.log(results);
};

var fn_1 = function(i, callback) {
console.log("fn_ 1 called with this argument " +i);
callback(null, "from function 1");
};


d3.queue(1)
    .defer(function(url, callback) { 
    d3.csv(url, function(data) {
    test_data = data.map(function(d) { return fn_parse_m_tot(d);});
    callback(null, "hi there in first function");
    });

}, url)

 .defer(fn_1, "arg1")
 .await(finished);
```

I am expecting the following results when the function finished() executes:

"hi there in first function"

"from function 1"

But I only get the following:

"hi there in first function"

The callback embedded in fn_1() does not seem to execute...?

Comment: Sorry, I should amend the question above to.
Expecting:

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in `.defer` is an asynchronous task (i.e. a function). All subsequent arguments are the (optional) arguments for that task. Your first task requires a url and a callback, so you have to provide them, otherwise they will be undefined in your task's body.

You could declare your task `fn_0` first:

```
var fn_0 = function(url, callback) {
  console.log('fn_0 (url: ' + url + '; callback: ' + callback + ')');
  d3.csv(url, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('d3.csv was called but there was an error downloading the data');
      throw error;
    };
    test_data = data.map(function(d) { return fn_parse_m_tot(d); });
    callback(null, "from fn_0");
  });
};
```

`fn_1` is another task for your queue. You don't have to change anything here.

`fn_2` is your callback:

```
var fn_2 = function(a, b) {
  console.log('fn_2 (a: ' + a + '; b: ' + b + ')');
};
```

Now the code in your queue is much more readable:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(fn_0, 'url-to-your-csv-file', fn_2)
  .defer(fn_1, 'arg1', fn_2)
  .await(finished);
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jackaljack/xe1rftwz/).

Note that if you write `d3.queue(1)`, all your tasks will be run in series, so a task will only run if all previous tasks succeed.

See the [d3-queue API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#api-reference).